# Passing parameters from processor to controller; VST 3.5

Tags: c++, vst

I'm new here so first of all: "Hello everybody!!"

I have a sincere problem with passing parameter changes from the process() to the the controller via `data.outputParameterChanges`. Take a look at the following code (`kDataParamId` is an ID of a properly set up parameter):

```
tresult PLUGIN_API AGain::process (ProcessData& data) 
{ 
IParameterChanges* paramChanges = data.outputParameterChanges; 

if (paramChanges) 
{ 
    int32 index; 
    IParamValueQueue* paramQueue = 
           paramChanges->addParameterData(kDataParamId, index);  

    if(paramQueue) 
    { 
        paramQueue->addPoint(0, 0.1, index); 
        paramQueue->addPoint(0, 0.2, index);              
        paramQueue->addPoint(0, 0.3, index);              

        fprintf(stderr 
           , "[MyVSTPlugin] paramQueue->getPointCount() == %d\n" 
           , paramQueue->getPointCount()); 
    } 

  } 
  return kResultOk; 
}
```

What I get with this a point count of "1". Furthermore, `setParamNormalized()` (as part of the controller which receives parameter changes) is called once from the host with "0.3". I might be naive, but I expected the parameter point count to return "3" and hence three calls to `setParamNormalized()` with 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3. What am I missing here????

Any help and comment on this is highly appreciated!

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to send parameters back to the controller from the processor using parameter changes.
You need to use the IConnectionPoint API and send messages.

You can send audio parameter from controller to the processor only. And the host can also send to the processor directly (but the host also notifies the controller when he send a parameter to the processor to let the controller update the editor view)

The outputparameterchanges member in the data is only read by the host after.

Now the question could also be WHY would you like to send messages back to the controller from the processor ?

For that the SDK gives the example of how to update an audio callback meter using IMessages